# What Python-only HTTP/1.1 web servers are available?

Tags: python, http

There is CherryPy. Are there any others?

Comment: cherrypy is a web framework, not an http server

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html ?

Comment: @hop: You can run CherryPy as a standalone HTTP server.  I do this myself quite often, running it behind Apache using mod_rewrite and mod_proxy.  This can be useful for a number of reasons, such as running background threads in the same process as your web server.

Comment: still, cherrypy _is_ a web framework and _contains_ a web server.

Comment: That's a little pedantic, isn't it? And a misread of @pommonico's question. If he had said "what are the HTTP 1.1 web servers available", being pedantic about a web framework that contains a server or not would make more sense. But by stating "python-only" he clearly is interested in a web-application framework.

Answer (score 2):

[magnum-py](http://code.google.com/p/magnum-py/)

or...

[Make your own!](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php)

Comment: I'd really recommend not making your own if it is connected to the internet. Securing web servers is an art. For intranet applications, BaseHttpServer provides a good start.

Comment: I would also recommend not making you own either unless you had a really good reason.  However, I thought the link was useful for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Twisted includes a [web server](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb).

Answer (score 1):

also:

web.py (webpy.org)

paste (pythonpaste.org)